# Python list iteration and join

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to write a function that returns a string that looks like this (2,3|5,6|8,9), but my function on returns a blank string

```
numbers = [(4,5,6),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]
def get_numbers(x):
  mystring = ""
  x = sorted(x)
  for n in x:
    if mystring is not "":
      mystring+="|"
    mystring+",".join(str(z) for z in n[1:])
  return mystring
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you get from `[(4,5,6),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]` to `'(2,3|5,6|8,9)'`?

Comment: Hence the gimmick of `[1:]` I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tiny bug. You typed `mystring=` instead of `mystring +=`

```
numbers = [(4,5,6),(1,2,3),(7,8,9)]
def get_numbers(x):
  mystring = ""
  x = sorted(x)
  for n in x:
    if mystring is not "":
      mystring+="|"
    mystring+=",".join(str(z) for z in n[1:])
  return mystring
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **join** for change list and tuple to string

```
values = map(lambda x: x[1:], sorted(numbers))

print "|".join([",".join(map(str, value)) for value in values])
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun, a ugly one liner ;-)

```
'(' + '|'.join([','.join(map(str, l[1:])) for l in numbers]) + ')'
```

I also added the brackets as you wrote that you want a string looking like this.